# PHP Error : 30711 with no explanation on what is the issue

Tags: php, email

I am getting `PHP Error : 30711` with no explanation on what is the issue.

How to see the error msg? Normally the error message will be displayed but not for this.
I am trying to use the `mail()` to send email.

Comment: I've given -1 on the question, because you didn't tell us anything about the program you're running, or what you've done to try to find out about the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP (at least in PHP 3.5), the number 30711 is the magic number for the `E_ALL` error code.

There's no reason for PHP to output this number, or for you to ever need to know it.

My guess is that your `error_reporting` setting is `E_ALL`, and the program you're running has a line that looks like this:

```
print "PHP Error: ".error_reporting();
```

In other words, it's a message that has been put in there deliberately by the programmer to tell them what the error setting is. Possibly it's in a debug part of the code? I don't know.

Given that, I'm fairly sure that the `mail()` function is not relevant to the question.

Comment: yes , i have this line ... how can i display the error msg then ? there is error but the error msg not shown...

I have this
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
        //error_reporting(E_ERROR);

Comment: That line is not an error; it is simply telling you the setting of the  PHP config value that determines what kind of errors are shown. I don't know why your program would want to tell you that, but the one thing it isn't doing is reporting any kind of error.